# how do i add images to db browser for sql?

Tags: sql, database, image, load

Do any of you know how to add images to database table. like for example I have lists of items and I want to put the image of the item as well so it will appear beside my list view.

Such as below,

[image]

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column and Datatype should be Varbinary(max).

INSERT INTO Table (Photo) 
SELECT 
 BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\test.jpg') as image

Comment: when I insert the new column, it doesn't have varbinary. Only have integer,text,blob,real & numeric

Comment: Which Version of SQL Server are you using ?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2